Include Cloudpage URL link in whatsapp message
I want to share a link to a custom preference center page in my WhatsApp business chat. When the user clicks the link to provide input, I want to ensure that the customer doesn't have to leave the WhatsApp interface. Can anyone help me understand how to achieve this?
